# Steps Needed to Install .Net and SQL Express on Windows Server 2012

Tags: installation, powershell, windows-server-2012, sql-server

Please forgive the simplicity of this question, but I work mostly with Linux servers and older versions of Windows Server. My exact question is how are packages installed on Windows Server 20212, given the error message that a roles cannot be installed without using cmdlets on Power Shell or the server manager.

I have downloaded .Net 3.5, SQL Express 2012, and the SQL Express Management Studio to a Windows 2012 server. Upon trying to install .Net 3.5 I got the familiar error message that the following feature could not be installed. I had to use server roles or cmd servlets in Power Shell.

I tried installing roles from Server Manager, but could not find in the menus installing a package externally. I also tried running PowerShell as Administrator. My login is an Administrator login, a domain administrator, but with admin privileges on the local server.

I have been looking for solutions, but none so far describing how to work with these new tools.

I'm not looking for a complete solution to my problem as much as a place to go find the steps to install these packages according to the new rules in Server 2012. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had no issues. I simply went to Google, typed in .net version (eg, .NET 3.5) and ran the thing and it automatically installs. What is your message in more detail. Also see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002547 Did you attempt to do it by adding roles?

Comment: I read through your post twice, but I really can't tell what you are asking. The text you posted doesn't even contain a question mark. Could you [edit] your question to include the specific question that you want us to answer?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Edited OP per suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server Manager, click Manage and then select Add Roles and Features to start the Add Roles and Features Wizard.

On the Select installation type screen, select Role-based or feature-based installation.

Select the target server.

On the Select features screen, check the box next to .Net Framework 3.5 Features.

On the Confirm installation selections screen, a warning will be displayed asking Do you need to specify an alternate source path?. If the target computer does not have access to Windows Update, click the Specify an alternate source path link to specify the path to the \sources\sxs folder on the installation media and then click OK. After you have specified the alternate source, or if the target computer has access to Windows Update, click the X next to the warning, and then click Install.

The big part here is the alternate source portion. If you have your Windows 2012 installation disk point it to that, if not it will need to access the internet for Windows Update.

Comment: Forgot to run server manager as Administrator .Net 3.5 installing now. tnx

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working out for you. Yeah, sometimes Windows can be finicky with how it allows for installs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to server manager and select ADD Roles and features in that go to features section the first option will be .NET Framework Features select that and proceed further. [image]